# How to use lowercase marks as global in vim?

Tags: vim

How can one use the lowercase marks as global buffers too?

The marks are a-z, so there's really no need for me to have the lowercase ones reserved for buffer-only marks, since I don't have more than a few marks / buffer.

So I will almost always want to have global marks, but `ma` is so much easier to type than `mA`, same goes for `'a` vs `'A`.

Comment: I didn't get what a global mark would mean so I tried this out. Cool stuff! - it switches you back to the buffer where you set the mark. Sorry I don't have an answer, but thanks for teaching me something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just map them by the look of it. Eg in your vimrc

```
nnoremap ma mA
nnoremap 'a 'A
nnoremap `a 'A
```

Although I suspect this approach might trip up plugins that aren't using nnoremap.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched a good amount of time for a proper solution and found nothing so I came back to the idea behind [michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1844610/6219628)'s answer and wrote this tiny script.

```lua
-- Use lowercase for global marks and uppercase for local marks.
local low = function(i) return string.char(97+i) end
local upp = function(i) return string.char(65+i) end

for i=0,25 do vim.keymap.set("n", "m"..low(i), "m"..upp(i)) end
for i=0,25 do vim.keymap.set("n", "m"..upp(i), "m"..low(i)) end
for i=0,25 do vim.keymap.set("n", "'"..low(i), "'"..upp(i)) end
for i=0,25 do vim.keymap.set("n", "'"..upp(i), "'"..low(i)) end
```

This will create all 26 letter remaps such that:

- `m<lowercase>` creates a new global mark
- `m<uppercase>` creates a new local mark
- `'<lowercase>` goes to a global mark
- `'<uppercase>` goes to a local mark

I prefer this over adding 4x26 lines in my config

Note that in lua, `vim.keymap.set` is "non-recursive" by default hence why you can replace lowercase with uppercase and vice versa.

If you don't use lua you can always write the previous script in vim script like this:

```
lua << EOF
script here
EOF
```